# What is this site's definitions of development methodologies?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[I have a question that was put on hold a little while ago.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227738/how-do-i-get-a-project-owner-to-participate-in-acceptance-testing?noredirect=1#comment452842_227738) Not the end of the world, it was a question about agile development and that's not strictly a programmer topic. But [when I looked at the on topic page I noticed that development methodologies was listed as the fourth item as on topic.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Then I went over to Wikipedia just to check to make sure that [development methodologies would include Agile development.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_methodology)

At this point, I'm unsure why the question was closed. To my mind it seems to fit the on topic portion of this Stack Exchange. So what about my question is off-topic? How could I phrase it differently to be on-topic?

Answer (score 12):

I think your question is definitely on topic so I've reopened it. Sometimes we (the community) get things wrong, so bringing it up here is the right thing to do.

Watch me get down voted on this one though.

Comment: I concur with your decision.  It is clearly on topic as it is about approaching the problem from the standpoint of development methodologies and not so much about workplace issues.

Comment: +1 for reopening a clearly on-topic question.